# Trouble with Google Protobuf Serializer dependency when upgrading from Python2 to Python3

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, protocol-buffers

I have some old Python2 code I have to upgrade to Python3 and it's currently using the google.protobuf library to serialize data to be sent to rabbitMQ. Java code then picks this up on the other end and deserializes. I can't update the Java code with a newly generated pb2 file that's supported by Python3. Python3 won't allow me to use the old Python2.7 pb2 file as the old google protobuf dependency has many errors.

Example:

```
  File , line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
  File "venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor_pool as _descriptor_pool
  File "venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor_pool.py", line 1291, in <module>
    _DEFAULT = DescriptorPool()
  File "venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor_pool.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._internal_db = descriptor_database.DescriptorDatabase()
AttributeError: module 'google.protobuf.descriptor_database' has no attribute 'DescriptorDatabase'
```

I've tried adding future dependency to the protobuf file but this doesn't help at all. What should I do here? Does it even matter if I upgrade the serializer file but leave the deserializer code the same? If so, how should I get this old library to work on python3.9?

Comment: I'm curious, is there protobuf3 python generated file backwards compatible with a protobuf2 deserializer?

Comment: Your question is unclear. For a specific proto (services, messages etc.), `protoc` will compile the proto into language-specific stubs that should (!) interoperate. I think your approach should be to start with the proto(s), generate stubs (preferably using a current version of `protoc`) and test these against your existing infrastructure (RabbitMQ, Java). Once you're confident the new stubs work correctly, revise the upgraded-to Python3 code to use the new bindings.

Comment: Google has changed the way that protoc builds Python stubs including a [breaking change](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06) earlier this year.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.